# Manipulating JSON data using angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs

I am trying to display the questions based on the json response. Here is my code snippet:

```
function BackgroundInfoController($scope, $http, $location, profileInfo) {
    $scope.master = {};
    $scope.questions = {};
    $scope.backgroundInfo = profileInfo.backgroundInfo;
    $http.get("/ERegII-1.0/public/test/", { cache: true })
    .success(function(data) {
        /*alert(JSON.stringify(data));*/
    $scope.questions = data;
    }).error(function(data) {
        alert("fail:" + JSON.stringify(data));
        // TODO display error messages.
    });
```

Now I am trying to display the data on the page using angular controller, something like this:

```
<div data-ng-controller="BackgroundInfoController">
    <ol>
    <li data-ng-repeat="question in questions"> {{question.displayText}}<br> 
    {{question.responseType}} 
    </li>
    <div reponse-type="question.responseType" ref-data="question.demographicResponses">

    </div>
</ol>

    </div>
```

The json data that I am getting is in following format:

```
 [
     {
          "seqNo":0,
          "qstnNo":34,
          "responseType":"F",
          "responseRequired":false,
          "displayText":"If you have been provided with a state ID enter it here",
          "demographicResponses":[

          ],
          "dependentQuestionVO":[

          ],
          "selectedResponseIds":[

          ],
          "freeFormAnswer":null,
          "response":"",
          "independent":true,
          "answered":false,
          "triggered":false
       },
       {
          "seqNo":2,
          "qstnNo":2,
          "responseType":"R",
          "responseRequired":true,
          "displayText":"What is your ethnicity?",
          "demographicResponses":[
             {
                "possibleResponse":"Non-Hispanic",
                "seqNo":2,
                "respNo":201
             },
             {
                "possibleResponse":"Hispanic",
                "seqNo":2,
                "respNo":202
             },
             {
                "possibleResponse":"I prefer not to respond",
                "seqNo":2,
                "respNo":203
             }
    ]

 "dependentQuestionVO":[
         {
            "dependentQstnNo":3,
            "triggerRespNo":202,
            "triggerArrayElement":"[202,3]"
         }
      ],
      "selectedResponseIds":[
         "201",
         "202",
         "203"
      ],
      "freeFormAnswer":null,
      "response":"Non-Hispanic
Hispanic
I prefer not to respond
",
      "independent":false,
      "answered":true,
      "triggered":true
   },
   {
      "seqNo":3,
      "qstnNo":3,
      "responseType":"R",
      "responseRequired":true,
      "displayText":"What is your Hispanic origin?",
      "demographicResponses":[
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Mexican, Mexican, or Chicano",
            "seqNo":3,
            "respNo":301
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Puerto Rican or Puerto Rican American",
            "seqNo":3,
            "respNo":302
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Cuban or Cuban American",
            "seqNo":3,
            "respNo":303
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Other",
            "seqNo":3,
            "respNo":304
         }
      ],
      "dependentQuestionVO":[

      ],
      "selectedResponseIds":[
         "301",
         "302",
         "303",
         "304"
      ],
      "freeFormAnswer":null,
      "response":"Mexican, Mexican, or Chicano
Puerto Rican or Puerto Rican American
Cuban or Cuban American
Other
",
      "independent":true,
      "answered":true,
      "triggered":false
   },
   {
      "seqNo":4,
      "qstnNo":4,
      "responseType":"M",
      "responseRequired":true,
      "displayText":"What is your race? Select all that apply.",
      "demographicResponses":[
         {
            "possibleResponse":"American Indian or Alaskan Native",
            "seqNo":4,
            "respNo":401
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Asian",
            "seqNo":4,
            "respNo":402
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Black or African American",
            "seqNo":4,
            "respNo":403
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander",
            "seqNo":4,
            "respNo":404
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"White",
            "seqNo":4,
            "respNo":405
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Other",
            "seqNo":4,
            "respNo":406
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"I prefer not to respond",
            "seqNo":4,
            "respNo":407
         }
      ],
      "dependentQuestionVO":[

      ],
      "selectedResponseIds":[
         "401",
         "402",
         "403",
         "404",
         "405",
         "406",
         "407"
      ],
      "freeFormAnswer":null,
      "response":"American Indian or Alaskan Native
Asian
Black or African American
Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander
White
Other
I prefer not to respond
",
      "independent":true,
      "answered":true,
      "triggered":false
   },
   {
      "seqNo":5,
      "qstnNo":5,
      "responseType":"R",
      "responseRequired":true,
      "displayText":"Do you communicate better (or as well) in English than in any other language?",
      "demographicResponses":[
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Yes",
            "seqNo":5,
            "respNo":501
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"No",
            "seqNo":5,
            "respNo":502
         }
      ],
      "dependentQuestionVO":[

      ],
      "selectedResponseIds":[
         "501",
         "502"
      ],
      "freeFormAnswer":null,
      "response":"Yes
No
",
      "independent":true,
      "answered":true,
      "triggered":false
   },
   {
      "seqNo":6,
      "qstnNo":6,
      "responseType":"R",
      "responseRequired":false,
      "displayText":"Which of the following best describes your current employment status?",
      "demographicResponses":[
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Employed part-time (29 or fewer hours per week)",
            "seqNo":6,
            "respNo":601
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Employed full-time",
            "seqNo":6,
            "respNo":602
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Unemployed (seeking employment)",
            "seqNo":6,
            "respNo":603
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Not in the labor force (homemaker, family caregiver, student, retired )",
            "seqNo":6,
            "respNo":604
         }
      ],
      "dependentQuestionVO":[

      ],
      "selectedResponseIds":[
         "601",
         "602",
         "603",
         "604"
      ],
      "freeFormAnswer":null,
      "response":"Employed part-time (29 or fewer hours per week)
Employed full-time
Unemployed (seeking employment)
Not in the labor force (homemaker, family caregiver, student, retired )
",
      "independent":true,
      "answered":true,
      "triggered":false
   },
   {
      "seqNo":7,
      "qstnNo":7,
      "responseType":"S",
      "responseRequired":false,
      "displayText":"What was the last grade of school that you completed?",
      "demographicResponses":[
         {
            "possibleResponse":"5th grade or lower",
            "seqNo":7,
            "respNo":701
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"6th grade",
            "seqNo":7,
            "respNo":702
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"7th grade",
            "seqNo":7,
            "respNo":703
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"8th grade",
            "seqNo":7,
            "respNo":704
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"9th grade (high school freshman)",
            "seqNo":7,
            "respNo":705
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"10th grade (high school sophomore)",
            "seqNo":7,
            "respNo":706
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"11th grade (high school junior)",
            "seqNo":7,
            "respNo":707
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"12th grade (high school senior)",
            "seqNo":7,
            "respNo":708
         }
      ],
```

Some questions are based on a specific answer for a question. Can someone help me to display these questions answers in agyularjs?
F=free form text, M= multiselect form (checkbox) and R= radio button.

Comment: A straightforward approach would be to use `ng-if` or `ng-switch` to chose the template to generate the question with. But a few custom directives might be nicer.

Answer (score 0):

This probably doesn't do exactly what you want, but it should provide a possible starting point.

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <ol ng-controller="ctrl">
        <li data-ng-repeat="question in questions"> 
          <div ng-switch on="question.responseType">
            <div ng-switch-when="F" textquestion="question"></div>
            <div ng-switch-when="R" radioquestion="question"></div>
            <div ng-switch-when="M" multiquestion="question"></div>
            <div ng-switch-when="S" selectquestion="question"></div>
          </div>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

The templates in these directives are a bit long, so it might be better to split them off as separate template and use `templateUrl` to get them. (And if you're never going to reuse them, you could just insert the templates in the html above.)

```
app.directive("textquestion", function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template : '<label>{{question.displayText}}<br/><input name="{{question.qstnNo}}" type="text"/></label>',
        scope : { question: '=textquestion' }
    };
})
.directive("radioquestion", function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template : '{{question.displayText}}<br/><label ng-repeat="resp in question.demographicResponses"><input  name="{{question.qstnNo}}" type="radio" value="{{resp.respNo}}" /> {{resp.possibleResponse}} </label> ',
        scope : { question: '=radioquestion' }
    };
})
.directive("multiquestion", function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template : '{{question.displayText}}<br/><label ng-repeat="resp in question.demographicResponses"><input  name="{{question.qstnNo}}" type="checkbox" value="{{resp.respNo}}" /> {{resp.possibleResponse}} </label>',
        scope : { question: '=multiquestion' }
    };
})
.directive("selectquestion", function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template : '{{question.displayText}}<br/><label> <select name="{{question.qstnNo}}"><option ng-repeat="resp in question.demographicResponses" value="{{resp.respNo}}"> {{resp.possibleResponse}}</option></select></label>',
        scope : { question: '=selectquestion' }
    };
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gwt3Q/

Comment: This is very neat! Thank you for your help Towr.

Comment: Towr- do you have any idea how can I add a class to the display text based on responseRequired == 'true'

Comment: @IrfanAli You can use ng-class, e.g. `<ANY ng-class="{someclass : question.responseRequired == 'true' }" >`

Comment: well.. I actually tried this like  <labe ng-class="{required: question.responseRequired = = 'true'}"> but somehow its not working!

Comment: Ok I got it! Here how it works: <ANY ng-class="{true: 'classname'} [question.responseRequired == true]">

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Towr! I guess its a good way to manipulate teh JSON. However, I have used different approach.

Here is my approach which works fine as of now :)

```
 <li ng-repeat="question in questions"><strong>{{question.displayText}}</strong><br> 
        <input type="text" ng-show="question.responseType == 'F'" name="questions.seqNo"  ng-model="answers[question.seqNo]" />

        <span ng-show="question.responseType == 'R'" data-ng-repeat=" demoResponse in question.demographicResponses">
        <input type="radio" ng-show="question.responseType == 'R'" name="{{questions.seqNo}}"  ng-model="answers[question.seqNo]" value="{{ demoResponse.respNo }}" /> {{demoResponse.possibleResponse}} <br>
        </span>
         <span ng-show="question.responseType == 'M'" data-ng-repeat=" demoResponse in question.demographicResponses">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-show="question.responseType == 'M'" name="M" ng-checked="answers[question.seqNo].indexOf(demoResponse.respNo) > -1" ng-click="toggleSelection(question.seqNo, demoResponse.respNo)"  /> {{demoResponse.possibleResponse}} <br>
        </span>

        <span ng-show="question.responseType == 'S'">
            <select data-ng-model="answers[question.seqNo]" >
                <option ng-repeat="demoResponse in question.demographicResponses" value="{{demoResponse.respNo}}">{{demoResponse.possibleResponse}}</option>
            </select>
         </span> 

    </li>
```

My Script code is here. I have also bind the data to the scope:

```
function BackgroundInfoController($scope, $http, $location, profileInfo) {
    $scope.master = {};
    $scope.questions = {};
    $scope.answers = {};
    $scope.backgroundInfo = profileInfo.backgroundInfo;
    $http.get("/ERegII-1.0/public/test/", { cache: true })
    .success(function(data) {
    /*  alert(JSON.stringify(data));*/
        $scope.questions = data;
        }).error(function(data) {
        alert("fail:" + JSON.stringify(data));
        // TODO display error messages.
    });


    $scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(seqNo, option) {
        if ($scope.answers[seqNo] == null) {
            $scope.answers[seqNo] = [];
        }
        var index = $scope.answers[seqNo].indexOf(option);
        if (index > -1) {
            $scope.answers[seqNo].splice(index, 1);
        } else {
            $scope.answers[seqNo].push(option);
        }
    //  alert($scope.answers[seqNo]);
    };
```